# Django command python manage.py runserver is not working

Tags: python, django, git-bash

The command python manage.py runserver is not giving any response. When i press enter after typing command  then the only thing which i get is:

```
HP@LAPTOP-3446CCM0 MINGW64 ~/downloads/src7/src7/mysite
$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

Nothing after this appears on the screen. But when i press `CTRL+C` then something like this appears on the screen:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
May 29, 2020 - 15:38:05
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

How to overcome through this

Comment: That's a strange behaviour. But the server is actually running!! First stop running that `StatReloader`, and see if your server will start normally.

Answer (score 0):

The server is working correctly, visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in your browser to see.

The message is telling you that you need to run migrations on your database. run `python manage.py migrate` and it will set up your database and remove that console output

Edit: To remove the stat reloader, you need to run the server with: `python manage.py runserver --noreload`

Comment: No after pressing enter i am only getting Watching for file changes with StatReloader  on  my screen and no other stuff even though i wait for a long time still it is showing                     Watching for file changes with StatReloader   and  no progress is there

Comment: But its still not working  after running   python manage.py runserver --noreload                      The scenario is like this                                                                                                          ` HP@LAPTOP-3446CCM0 MINGW64 ~/downloads/src7/src7/mysite
$ python manage.py runserver --noreload `
                                                                                                                                               After this nothing is coming up on the screen

Comment: So, I'm gonna guess that you are using PyCharm. There seems to be a bug with Django2.2 in PyCharm that explains this behaviour. See this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30323

The solution seems to be unchecking the "Preserve file timestamps on save" option in your PyCharm Settings

Comment: @Sam it seems he is using Django 3.0.6

Comment: Ah yep. Good catch